# Custom Error Page Set up in ssl.conf with jkmount

Tags: apache, ssl, mod-jk

I want to set up a custom error page under ssl.conf, i have already made it working without ssl with the same set up which i have posted below. But with ssl my browser is continuously saying "Establishing secure connection in chrome or tls handshaking in mozilla" For the path mention on server. However for URL it is working fine. Not sure what is going wrong.

```
Alias /error/ "/opt/apache/htdocs"
ErrorDocument 503 /error/maintenancepage.html 
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName  subdomain.com
    DocumentRoot /opt/apache/htdocs/
    RewriteEngine on
    <Directory /opt/apache/htdocs/>
            AllowOverride None
            Options None
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>        
    JkMount /* loadbalancer
    JkMount / loadbalancer
    JkMount     /*      loadbalancer;use_server_errors=503
    JkUnMount   /error/*   loadbalancer
    SSLEngine On
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLHonorCipherOrder On
    SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES198-SHA232:AES567-GCM SHA123:!RC6:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL:!EDH
    SSLCertificateFile "com.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "ssl.key"
    SSLCertificateChainFile "ca-bundle"
</VirtualHost>
```

Also server is working fine if i am commenting these two lines, but custom error page is not apearing.

```
JkMount     /*      loadbalancer;use_server_errors=503
JkUnMount   /error/*   loadbalancer
```

Also i am using rewrite in httpd.conf to rewrite all http urls to https like

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1%{REQUEST_URI}
```